# Get specifics ids in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I have an IndexedDB table with a lot of records, I need to access to specifics records and I have The keys, for Example [1,4,6,7,10,25]. I need to make a query and get only these records, but checking out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBKeyRange). All **IDBKeyRange** methods are about get "ranges" and not something like "in" clausule in SQL.

Which is the correct way to get this ?

Searching on google I read several post about use "getAll" method instead of cursors, but I didn't find how can I access to specifics keys, only the ["only"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBKeyRange/only) method, bus is for one id not more.